# MEF plugin application without probing config or assembly resolve event

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I'm trying to use MEF to facilitate a Add-in or Plug-in style architecture. I've done this with structure map in a very similar fashion before, but am seeing the same exact problem I had with structure map in that I have to either add a probing directory config to the app.config or set up an AssemblyResolve event handler to handle plugins that dynamically invoke code.

Here is the example MEF code (just a little lab app) that shows how I'm invoking a method from a specified interface:

```
namespace MefLab
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            MefLoader loader = new MefLoader();

            Type type = typeof(IConsoleWriter);

            Lazy<object, object> export = loader.Container.GetExports(type, null, null).SingleOrDefault();

            var writer = (IConsoleWriter)export.Value;

            writer.Write();

            Console.ReadKey();

        }

    }

    public class MefLoader
    {

        public MefLoader()
        {

            var registrationBuilder = new RegistrationBuilder();

            registrationBuilder.ForTypesDerivedFrom<IConsoleWriter>().SetCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared).Export<IConsoleWriter>();

            var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();

            var mefLabInfraCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(IConsoleWriter).Assembly);

            aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(mefLabInfraCatalog);

            foreach (string pluginDir in PluginDirctories)
            {
                DirectoryCatalog dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(pluginDir, registrationBuilder);
                aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(dirCatalog);
            }

            var coreCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(MefLoader).Assembly);

            aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(coreCatalog);

            Container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);

            // used if no probing path is used in app.config
            // AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;

        }

        public CompositionContainer Container { get; set; }

        private List<String> _pluginDirectories;
        private List<String> PluginDirctories
        {
            get
            {
                if (_pluginDirectories == null)
                {
                    _pluginDirectories = new List<string>();

                    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Plugins"));

                    foreach (DirectoryInfo dInfo in di.GetDirectories())
                    {
                        _pluginDirectories.Add(dInfo.FullName);
                    }
                }
                return _pluginDirectories;
            }
        }

        private List<Assembly> _assemblies;
        private List<Assembly> Assemblies
        {
            get
            {
                if (_assemblies == null)
                {
                    _assemblies = new List<Assembly>();

                    foreach (string pluginDir in PluginDirctories)
                    {
                        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(pluginDir);

                        foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles("*.dll"))
                        {
                            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(fi.FullName);
                            //assembly.GetTypes();
                            _assemblies.Add(assembly);
                        }
                    }

                    DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)));
                    foreach (FileInfo fi in root.GetFiles("*.dll"))
                    {
                        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(fi.FullName);
                        //assembly.GetTypes();
                        _assemblies.Add(assembly);
                    }
                    foreach (FileInfo fi in root.GetFiles("*.exe"))
                    {
                        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(fi.FullName);
                        //assembly.GetTypes();
                        _assemblies.Add(assembly);
                    }

                }
                return _assemblies;
            }
        }

        Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            Assembly resolved = Assemblies.Where(x => x.FullName == args.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            return resolved;
        }

    }

}
```

Here is what I'm talking when I say a plugin that invokes code dynamically.

```
namespace MefLabDependency.Managers
{
    public class EntityConsoleManager : IConsoleWriter
    {

        public void Write()
        {
            var domProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<String, String>{{ "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" }});

            List<string> assemblies = (from Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                              where !assembly.IsDynamic && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(assembly.Location) select assembly.Location).ToList();

            var parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            parameters.CompilerOptions = "/optimize";
            parameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(assemblies.ToArray());

            CompilerResults results = domProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,
            @"using System;
              using MefLabDependency.Entities;
                namespace MefLabDependency.DynamicCode
                {
                    public class EntityBuilder {
                      public static string GetValue() {
                            Entity entity = new Entity();
                            var value = string.Format(@""{2}EntityId: {0}{2}Name: {1}\"", entity.Id, entity.Name, System.Environment.NewLine);
                            return value;
                      }
                    }
                }");

            Assembly dynamicAssembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
            Type dynamicType = dynamicAssembly.GetType("MefLabDependency.DynamicCode.EntityBuilder");

            // this line bombs out if no probing path or assembly resolver event is configured with "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."
            // that ends up specifying that is can't reslove that assembly the type of Entity is located in.
            object objValue = dynamicType.InvokeMember("GetValue", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, null, null);

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Dynamic code execution success!{0}", objValue);

        }

    }
}
```

My question is... Is there another way?! (e.g. a better way) Using the probing config works fine, but everytime you add a plugin, you need to add a probing directory to the config, which is something I'd like to avoid if possible.

This is the probing config I speak of:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="Plugins\MefDependencyPlugin"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Adding the AssemblyResolve event handler also works, but it seems hackish, and I'm not certain how this works in production (where I have no idea what each assembly is doing other that the fact it implements an interface and a method is invoked on concretions from the plugins).

If these are the only solutions to this issue, so be it, but I figured the collective smarts of stack may be able to provide another suggestion. Maybe there's a better framework to use other than MEF or StructureMap that can handle this without config or event handlers?

Comment: Why not just enumerate all the assemblies in plugin subfolder and add them to the catalog?

Comment: That doesn't address the question I'm asking. Even if I do that, the problem I'm pointing out still exists. You still end up having to add a probing path or assembly resolve event. To me, MEF should handle adding all plugin dir assemblies to the app domain.